# Can get Play 2.2 details when running JUnit testing with Play 2.3

Tags: testing, junit, playframework, typesafe-activator

I'm having issue with play framework and JUnit test with play 2.3

When running: "activator test" then it runs fine, but...

```
[info] Loading project definition from /.../test/toto/project
[info] Set current project to toto (in build file:/home/jenkins/.../)
[info] Compiling 6 Java sources to /home/jenkins/automated_tests/.../toto/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[warn] application - do execute tests in class utils.UtilsTest
[warn] application - do execute tests in class test_marketcity.BasicTest
[info] Passed: Total 14, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 14
[success] Total time: 29 s, completed Feb 12, 2015 9:48:51 AM
```

There's nothing about the test which have been run, only the full total of test (14 here). With play 2.2 I had a more detailled log containing also each test:

```
[info] x firstTest (x means here it failed)
[info] + secondTest (+ means here it succeeded)
```

Should I have to put a specific option here to get more details ?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

It is a common issue with tests on activator. I usually run `activator clean` before tests to get the output. Sometimes running tests from sbt helps.